# Changing a div to Text Box?

Tags: asp.net

I have a div area like the following in my .aspx program.

```
   <div id="valueIntroduction" type="text" class="labelarea" runat="server">  
   </div>
   <div  class="line"></div>

  <asp:Button ID="editButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
```

Currently the div `valueIntroduction` is getting data from database. I have a `Edit button` in my program. When i press Edit button I am trying to change the div to text box.

Comment: Why not ide the div and show a text box on click or add the attribute to the div 'contentEditable='true''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

1.Add a textbox and make `visible="false"`

2.when clicking edit button copy the div's contents to the textbox and make div invisible by using `visibility:"hidden"`.

3.Set the textbox visibility to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an invisible textbox below your div, then when you click the edit button, transfer the contents of the div into the textbox, make the textbox visible and the div invisible.